# .NetCore 3.1 Webapi not post string in action

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I upgraded a webapi solution from 2.1 to 3.1.

My Startup.cs file contains:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddControllers();
   services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();
..

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   if (env.IsDevelopment())
   {
       app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
   }

   app.UseRouting();
   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
..
```

My controller starts with:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class MyFooController : Controller
```

and here is my action:

```
[HttpPost]
public string MyFooAction(string value)
```

So I call action from another easy solution with:

```
var param = new NameValueCollection();
param["value"] = "3";
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var data = client.UploadValues(url, "POST", param);
```

In debug, the call gets the action route but value=null always.
I also tried with [FromBody] but it's the same.

I read in 3.1 would be prefer inherint controller from ControllerBase class but I have many action that return Json(obj) and that is not present in ControllerBase class but only in Contreller class: is this the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @CodeIT, any updates about this case? Have you resolved the issue with the solution I shared?

Comment: Hi Fei, sorry... not practice... Have I well done now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> var data = client.UploadValues(url, "POST", param);

> the call gets the action route but value=null always

Using `WebClient.UploadValues` method to post the value(s) to the server, you can try to apply `[FromForm]` attribute to your action parameter, as below.

```
[HttpPost]
public string MyFooAction([FromForm]string value)
{

    //...
```

Test Result

[image]

Besides, you can achieve same requirement using `WebClient.UploadString` method to post data through request body.

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
    var data = client.UploadString(url, "POST", "3");
    //...
}
```

*Action method*

```
[HttpPost]
public string MyFooAction([FromBody]string value)
{

    //...
```

Test Result

[image]